# Calling variable within Ionic constructor returns UNDEFINED

Tags: javascript, cordova, variables, ionic-framework, constructor

How can I call a variable in a constructor?

```
constructor ( private auth: AngularFireAuth ) {
this.auth.authState.subscribe((user)=> {this.email = user.email});

this.url = 'http://localhost/check.php' + this.email;  
// NOW CALLIG this.email RETURN UNDEFINED. HOW CAN I MAKE IT WORK?
..........
..........
}
```

For an unavoidable reason I cannot add `'http://localhost/check.php' + this.email;` after `{this.email = user.email;`

Comment: not possible... Observables are asynchronous.. your `this.url` assignment is happening before the subscribe function gets called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can try [life cycle methods in Nav Controller](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) which can be triggered in different stages of page events.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do the call in the subscriber. Or call a function from inside than you know your variables are set.

```
constructor ( private auth: AngularFireAuth ) {
this.auth.authState.subscribe((user)=> {
this.email = user.email;
this.url = 'http://localhost/check.php' + this.email; 
// NOW CALLIG this.email
})
}
```

// edit

```
constructor ( private auth: AngularFireAuth ) {
    this.auth.authState.subscribe((user)=> {
    checkEmail(user.email).then((valid) => 
    {
        if(valid) {
            this.email = user.email
            this.url = 'http://localhost/check.php' + this.email; 
        }
    }
})
}

checkEmail(email: string): Promise<boolean>
{
    let valid = false;
    //email valid? -> verify the email is valid, if yes return true

    return valid;

}
```

-> not tested

Comment: A security hole will open if I call another external domain in  `// NOW CALLIG this.email `